# How can I install docker toolbox on windows 7

Tags: docker, boot2docker, kitematic

Docker and kitematic can't be launch after a successfull installation of docker-toolbox.

I have this error when launching kitematic :

```
Error: connect ENOENT //./pipe/docker_engine
```

And also :

```
Command failed: C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker-machine.exe -D create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-memory 2048 default,Docker Machine Version: 0.8.2, build e18a919,Found binary path at C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker-machine.exe,Launching plugin server for driver virtualbox,Plugin server listening at address 127.0.0.1:53159,() Calling .GetVersion,Using API Version 1,() Calling .SetConfigRaw,() Calling .GetMachineName,(flag-lookup) Calling .GetMachineName,(flag-lookup) Calling .DriverName,(flag-lookup) Calling .GetCreateFlags,Found binary path at C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker-machine.exe,Launching plugin server for driver virtualbox,Plugin server listening at address 127.0.0.1:53163,() Calling .GetVersion,Using API Version 1,() Calling .SetConfigRaw,() Calling .GetMachineName,(default) Calling .GetMachineName,(default) Calling .DriverName,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to uninstall virtualbox et docker-toolbox.

Then I reinstalled with NDSI5 driver.

[image]

Comment: It was not help for me

Answer (score 0):

1. Run Kitematic (It was install with docker toolbox)
2. Click "Use VM"
3. Click "Docker CLI" in Kitematic